Run TensorFlow 2.17 on CPU without AVX
I would like to install tensorflow on a Windows system with a processor that does not seem to support AVX (Pentium J6426).
I saw that a minority of people had this problem in the past with earlier version of the library. For example here. The best option for me would be to find some 2.17 (or 2.18) wheels already built without AVX support.
As I don't find them on the internet, I wonder if it is at all possible or too difficult to build tensorflow myself. Is it matter of changing a compilation option and run the make file or is it more complicated? I found instructions but the seems to refere to earlier versions of tensorflow.
Cheers!

Hi @Alkhwarizmi, Please refer to this official page of TensorFlow Install and follow the given step by step instructions to install the Tensorflow in your system. Let us know incase any issue.  Thank you.
